# Applying chain rule to $(e^x)^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When applying chain rule to the $n$-th power of a function of $x$, the power of the function is reduced to $n-1$. Why doesn’t this occur when taking the derivative of $(e^x)^n$?

Comment: Why would it? $e^x\neq x$

Comment: It does occur. But you have to fully apply the chain rule. The derivative of $f^n$ is $f'nf^{n-1}$, not $nf^{n-1}$.

Comment: You can treat $f(x)=(e^x)^n$ using chain rule, and this gives you $f'(x)=n(e^x)^{n-1}e^x=n(e^x)^n$. You can transform it as $f(x)=e^{nx}$ and get (chain rule again) $f'(x)=e^{nx}\cdot n$. Either way, you get the same result.

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain rule works just fine: $$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(e^x\right)^n =
n \left(e^x\right)^{n-1} \frac{d}{dx} e^x =
n \left(e^x\right)^{n-1} e^x = n \left(e^x\right)^n = ne^{nx}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the product rule:

$$(e^x)^n = e^x \times e^x \times \cdots \times e^x$$

$$\begin{align}
\implies \frac d{dx} (e^x)^n &= (\color{red}{e^x} \times e^x \times \cdots \times e^x) + (e^x \times \color{red}{e^x} \times \cdots \times e^x) + \cdots + (e^x \times e^x \times \cdots \times \color{red}{e^x}) \\
&= n (e^x \times e^x \times \cdots \times e^x) \\
&= n(e^x)^n
\end{align}$$